# Essential singularity of a function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a$ $∈$ $\mathbb{C}$ and $r > 0$ be a real number. We denote $U = \mathbb{D}(a, r)­/ \{a\}$. Let
$f ∈ O(U)$ an holomorphic function such that $\mathfrak{R}$f(z) ≥ $0$ for all $z \in U$.

1) Show that $a$ is not an essential singularity of $f$.

2) Show that $f$ can be extend in an holomorphic function on all the disc $\mathbb{D}(a,r)$.

Since we had no class about this subject, I'm not quite sure about how to start this problem. Any ideas? 
For what I understand, for 1) I have to show that the point $a$ is either a pole or a removable singularity is this correct? 
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, there are $3$ types of singularities-removable, pole and essential. So you have to show $a$ is not an essential singularity. This can be easily done if you know Casorati-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Do you know how to map the upper half plane into the unit disk (by a biholomorphism)? Then you may think about using Riemann removable singularity theorem

Comment: I'm not quite sure which theorems I can use since we didn't prove any. #corona

Comment: Without knowing what thorems you know about Complex Analysis it is hard to answer this question.

Comment: duplicate of the following which has 3 different (all excellent if I may say so as one is mine) solutions so you can choose your pick of them https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625544/why-a-is-not-an-essential-singularity-and-how-f-can-be-extended/3625608#3625608